# python statement " if value is in [,] "

Tags: python, string

I am trying to understand a open source code from the following link:
https://github.com/alexbaucom17/DominoRobot/blob/master/src/tools/plot_logs.py

Can anybody explain what exactly happening in the line: `if c in ['[',']',',','\n']:`

```
def get_value(line, path):
    idx = 0
    for p in path:
        idx = line.find(p, idx)
        idx += len(p)

    data = ""
    for c in line[idx:]:
        if c in ['[',']',',','\n']:
            break
        elif c in [':',' ']:
            continue
        else:
            data += c        

    return float(data)
```

Comment: what exactly do you not understand? the code is checking if `c` is one of the characters in the list, it returns `True` if `c` is either `[` or `]` or `,` or `\n` (newline)

Comment: Presumably the alternating `',',','` and `['['` can be quite confusing to read.

Answer (score 3):

The `in` operator checks for containment. So it is literally checking if the length-1 string `c` is one of the elements `[],\n`. If so, it ends the loop using `break` if not, it checks against `:` . Because of how containment checks work, and the fact that `c` is guaranteed by the loop to be a single character, you can implement the check like this:

```
if c in '[],\n':
    break
elif c in ': ':
    continue
else:
    data += c
```

While we're here, `data += c` is not a great way to accumulate strings, since they are immutable. You may be better off appending to a list instead:

```
data = []
for c in line[idx:]:
    ...
data = ''.join(data)
```

Better yet, record the index of the first element you find, slice the original, and remove the two undesirable characters:

```
for i, c in line[idx:]:
    if c in '[],\n':
        break
data = line[idx:i].replace(':', '').replace(' ', '')
```

Answer (score 2):

This code is not written to be read easily.

It would be better if it included some spaces to make it more clear:

```
if c in ['[', ']', ',', '\n']:
```

`['[', ']', ',', '\n']` is a list of four single-character string literals:

- `'['`
- `']'`
- `','`
- `'\n'` (the line break character)

This line tests if `c` is contained in the list, i.e., if it is equal to any of those four characters.

What can be even more confusing is that `[`, `]`, and `,` appear both as one of the four characters to be tested, and as part of the list syntax `[x, y, z]`.

Comment: Syntax highlighting goes a long way towards making it more legible.

Answer (score 0):

It is set to true if c has one of the values in the list, so if it is one of those characters.

It is the same as checking if c is equal to each item from the list, and if it is equal to any of them, it returns true.